# Xcode error : Expected identifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I Get an error stating "Expected Identifier" at this line of code

```
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4]];
```

This code is placed in the application Delegate as follows

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "FirstViewController.h"

#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "ParkTable.h"
#import "TableTest.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize ParkTableDel = _tableViewController;
@synthesize navController;




- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *viewController3 = [[ParkTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParkTable" bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *viewController4 = [[TableTest alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableTest" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4]];  

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.ParkTableDel = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;    
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

// [...] Boilerplate code removed.
@end
```

I was wondering what i have to change to make it correct.

Comment: Please copy/paste the Error log. Also, TableTest is an UITableViewController?

Answer (score 17):

Could it be the extra set of parentheses? [ ]

Comment: Hi, Thats fixed the code but the view appears to be a black screen when i click on that tab do you know whats wrong now?

Comment: Does that happen for all view controllers on your tab bar? Or you generally have a black screen? Is there anything in the nib files that your view controllers load with? Are they hooked up correctly in Interface Builder?

Comment: I get four Tabs the first two work fine as they are just normal view controllers. but the last two are the TableView and the navController1 when i click on the TableView it shows the table but the cells do not push their respective views and the third tab is the navController1 which shows a navigation bar and a black view with the tab bar at the bottom.

Comment: It's difficult to comment on why your table view cells aren't pushing more content without seeing the contents of the ParkTable or TestTable class files. As for your navController1, the black colour is likely because it has no background colour set. In -(void)viewDidLoad you can call self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; or whichever you like.

Comment: Can i give you a link to a zip of the code?

Comment: Sure, append your main post with a link.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Luke you have an extra set of parentheses.

To correct the black screen try..

```
[self.window addSubview: self.tabBarController.view]
```

Instead of ..

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: Hi, The tab bar shows in the black screen along with a navigation bar at the top. the black part is where the table should be. i should have been more clearer when i said "black screen".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It is probably the extra set of [] you have around your line of code.